# Is the child of a convert, conceived after she converted, Jewish?

Tags: halacha, women, conversion-to-judaism, children-parenting

If a woman converted before she conceived any children are they considered Jewish? Even with a non-Jewish father? I understand that non-Jewish mothers with Jewish husbands do not have Jewish children because the Jewish line is maternal, but I am referring to a woman who converted to Judaism prior to getting pregnant, which would make her a Jew. Would that make her children Jewish also because their mom is now considered Jewish, or is it a different situation than natural Jewish mothers?

Comment: Counterpart questions: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15102 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36228

Answer (score 7):

> If a woman converted before she conceived any children are they considered Jewish? Even with a non-Jewish father?

Yes. Children of a Jewish mother are Jewish, regardless. If mom converted she's Jewish. (A child who was in the mother's womb when mom converted is also Jewish, by the way.)

Comment: I’m not clear.... is OP asking if the mother’s relationship with the non-Jew puts the validity of her conversion in doubt? That could be a possibility.

Comment: @LN6595 separate question! The question as stated assumes that she actually *converted*.  Let's say for instance she converted with intention to keep everything, kept everything for fifteen years, at which point she still didn't find a Jewish husband, got lonely, and then married a non-Jew. *Presumably* her intent at the time of conversion was absolutely sincere -- in which case she's 100% Jewish.

Comment: Agreed. If the women converted without a clear intention to keep all the mitzvot, and subsequently had relations with a non-Jew, that might have a different answer.

Comment: From a careful reading of the question, it is not clear what type of conversion she did, or how sincere were her intentions. If she converted while still considering it okay to marry a non-Jew (perhaps intermarriage was tolerated by the community she joined), many would suspect the validity of the conversion, and hence her and her children's Jewish status.